# Need to find a point a given distance along a linestring

Tags: sql-server, boost, gis

Need to take a linestring and find a coord every x meters along the line. I tried using the SQL Server Spatial Tools and found .NET to be slow and after 5(ish) days of processing, SQL server (or .NET) just stops working.

I'm moving away from .NET to a native approach and still use SQL Server for its multi-threaded capabilities. I found boost and want to use it in place of .NET's geometry type, but I don't have the skill to create an algorithm that would find the coordinate along a linestring every x meters. I'm looking for said algorithm. Does anyone have a tip/pointer to what I could use?

Comment: This looks like it might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094268/moving-a-point-along-a-path-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0):

This [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549915/how-to-split-linestring-into-parts-every-x-meters-with-java-jts) may be what you need although you likely want to substitute the .NET wrapper library of [geographiclib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/)